# Calculus Vector Question

Tags: trigonometry

> Determine the component form for the 2-space vector $\mathbf w$ if it is known that its angle from the positive x-axis is $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ and its length is $11$.

Any input is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You basically already have $w$ in [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system), now you just have to convert it to Cartesian coordinates. And: (1) don't transcribe problems in a way that reads like you're telling us to do something, (2) nice gravatar.

Comment: My apologies :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've taken up polar coordinates, this is simply a matter of turning $(11,5\pi/4)$ into Cartesian coordinates.

See formulae 1-2 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarCoordinates.html) for the conversion formulae. $r$ there is length and $\theta$ is bearing, while $x,y$ are components.

Comment: Ah yes, this problem was among a bunch of 3d plane problems so I forgot the simple formula. Thanks!

Comment: After doing the calculations I think the component form for this vector should be <-7.78, -7.78> does that sound right?

Comment: @Matt: I prefer $-11/\sqrt 2$ myself, but sure...